# Media Wiki Main Page URL

Tags: .htaccess

I was just about to start my very own little Wiki and I was wondering if I can change the Main Page URL.

The Wiki is a standalone URL.. so no Subfolder or Subdomain is needed.

Well, after the install and some work to get the ShortURL working, I ended up with http://www.domain.tld/wiki/Hauptseite (Hauptseite is german for main page)

I would love to see this page just to be on http://www.domain.tld/ same content and all, so maybe a simple htaccess rule could handle this.

Any Idea how to get this working?

Just in case it is needed the .htaccess content

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?w/images/thumb/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2 [L,QSA,B]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?w/images/thumb/archive/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2&archived=1 [L,QSA,B]
```

Every help would be more than welcome!

Thanks

Comment: It's been a while since I last used MediaWiki, but does `RewriteRule ^$ /w/index.php?page=Hauptseite [L]` work? Also, an url does never start with a slash in .htaccess context, as the prefix-path is removed before the url is matched.

Comment: The htaccess was generated with http://shorturls.redwerks.org/ as it was gives in the manual to create the shortlinks. So i wasn't aware of and neither capable of to see and fix an error. Furthermore the htaccess and shortlinks as it are working, just the main page needs to be shown a bit different.... without /wiki/Hauptseite